# OneDrive corrupts macro enabled files

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

We are having a problem with some macro-enabled files. Since OneDrive was installed, some instances of the files get corrupt randomly.

Googling this issue I found some other people with the same problem (for instance https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-repeatedly-corrupting-macro-enabled/385043f9-4d1d-4502-89da-f3ee3c92f8d7 but none of them found a solution, or even root cause.

.xlsx files don't seem to get corrupted, so this makes me think there is a problem when OneDrive saves the file, and simultaneously some code is running, for instance a `Worsheet_Change` or a `Workbook_BeforeSave` macro.

Any ideas? Apart from not using OneDrive.

Edit:

In another forum somebody suggested that having the calculation in manual mode and then saving might be problematic. Well, this is a long shot, but I am going to add a

`Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False`

line before every existing

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

in the code.

Comment: In the link you provided looks like this might work: *I have turned off my OneDrive synchronisation and ran it every evening instead, without opening and closing the file whilst OneDrive synchronisation is active, and the file is happily saving every day without corrupting.* Have you tried?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns That means not using a valuable tool. Working with OneDrive allows to have the version history automatically saved. But we might end up doing it if no other solution is found. It is worse to deal with corrupted files periodically

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas? Apart from not using OneDrive.

I have the same issue. Excel files become corrupted if I edit an Excel Macro-Enabled worksheet, while OneDrive is running.

Once I discovered this problem, I disabled OneDrive from automatically starting up with Windows.

I have regular automatic backups with a third-party software, and I enable OneDrive only when/if synch is needed. Then I exit OneDrive.

This defeats the purpose of using OneDrive, but OneDrive is used by my organization, and this is the safest option I have to prevent corrupting important Excel files.

Another option that saved me several time was creating Excel files versions manually or via VBA automatically. For example

MySpreadsheet v01.00,
MySpreadsheet v01.01,
MySpreadsheet v01.02 ...etc

This saved my work several times. In case a file is corrupted, I can go back to the most recent version. (Microsoft suggests to use OneDrive built-in version history to restore files, but it's not reliable.)

As today, OneDrive still causes file corruption when running, and none of the Microsoft forum post I have read have a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not directly OneDrive but when you have file collaboration enabled. Still trying to get to the bottom of this  for a client but it seems to be there. I use OneDrive sync but had issues with file corruption early on so disabled the File Collaboration probably 2 years ago and have always kept it off since. I have had no issues with the xlsb or xlsx files syncing with OneDrive but the client does. The only difference (having checked versions of everything) is the file collaboration setting. MS needs to enable an option here to disable certain file types or file names from this setting. It is either on or off and if you need it for many things it makes it really difficult if it corrupts macro enabled Excel files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).